# How do I get the value of a select in code-behind?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and in my `.aspx` page I have the following code, and, based on the selection, I am displaying the appropriate `div`s.  It's working great, as is, but the question is: *How do I get the value (whatever selected by user) on code-behind?*

```
<select id="filterResultsBy"  >
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="Date">Date</option>
    <option value="Subject">Subject</option> 
    <option value="Status">Status</option>
</select>
```

If I add `runat="server"` or use the server `asp:DropDownList` control, jQuery does not work.

```
$('#ddlFilter').change(function(){ 
   var sel = $(this).val(); 
   if(sel === 'DATE'){ 
     hideAll();// a function to hide all the divs first 
     $('#divDateRangeSearch').show(); 
   } else if(sel === 'SUBJECT'){ 
     ///so on... 
   } 
});
```

Comment: Which part of jQuery's not working? The first selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET the usual convention is to use server side controls which work better with the Postback model. So you could use the equivalent:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="filterResultsBy" runat="server" CssClass="ddlFilter">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Select..." />
    <asp:ListItem Value="Date" Text="Date" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="Subject" Text="Subject" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="Status" Text="Status" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

which would allow you to access the `filterResultsBy` variable in the code behind and retrieve the currently selected value. To make this work with client scripting libraries such as `jQuery` add a class and use a class selector instead of id selector because of the name mangling that occurs in ASP.NET server side controls:

```
$('.ddlFilter').change(function() {
    var sel = $(this).val(); 
    if(sel === 'DATE') { 
        hideAll(); // a function to hide all the divs first 
        $('#divDateRangeSearch').show(); 
    } else if (sel === 'SUBJECT') { 
        ///so on... 
    } 
});
```

Comment: yes i know that i can easily use the server control but the problem is jquery is not working... i will udpate my question after i post this.

Comment: The other options besides a class selector is to set `ClientIDMode="Static"`, which will give the resultant select html the same id as the server-side control (without mangling the ID as usually happens).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `RunAt="Server"` to your select tag.

```
<select id="filterResultsBy" Runat="Server"  >
     <option value="">Select...</option>
     <option value="Date">Date</option>
     <option value="Subject">Subject</option> 
     <option value="Status">Status</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yes i did that but the problem is jquery is not working if i add runat server

Comment: You didn't mention jQuery in your original question. Edit it so as to make clear what the real problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a DropDownList control or add the runat="server" attribute to the select tag to upgrade it to a [HtmlSelect control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

another option (if you're looking to ajaxify your page) would be to keep your select as-is and just use a jquery ajax call to communicate via web/page methods.